# Multiple table query returns nothing in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a regular wp_users table and sh_users table.

wp_users table is standard one: ID,  user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name

sh_users table has: id (auto-increment), user_id (this matches wp_users ID), user_photo (Varchar 255), user_gender (varchar 255)

Now when I do query like this

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT user_login, user_email, user_photo
FROM wp_users, sh_users
WHERE wp_users.ID = sh_users.user_id
");
```

... and this is var dump of that query:

```
string '
SELECT user_login, user_email, user_photo
FROM wp_users, sh_users
WHERE wp_users.ID = sh_users.user_id
' (length=109)
```

It returns nothing... + no errors generated what so ever.... so I'm just asking what's the problem there ???

------UPDATE--------

This is dump for wp-users:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES 
(1, 'pete', 'xxxxxxx', 'pete', 'HIDDEN@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-02 16:42:04', '', 0, 'pete'),
(15, 'test', 'xxxxxx', 'test', 'HIDDEN@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-15 11:17:01', '', 0, 'test'),
(16, 'test1', 'xxxxx', 'test1', 'b.HIDDEN@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-15 20:05:32', '', 0, 'test1'),
(17, 'test5', 'xxxxxx', 'test5', 'HIDDEN.pe@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-16 09:48:57', '', 0, 'test5'),
(23, 'ban', 'xxxxx', 'ban', 'HIDDEN4@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-24 23:24:31', '', 0, 'bane'),
(24, 'ban2', 'xxxx', 'ban2', 'HIDDEN.HIDDEN@gmail.com', '', '2013-07-31 17:41:46', '', 0, 'ban2');
```

Mysql dump for sh_users:

```
---- Dumping data for table `sh_users`--
INSERT INTO `sh_users` (`id`, `user_id`, `user_registered`, `user_active`, `user_location`, `user_gender`, `user_photo`, `user_meet`, `user_text`, `user_subscribed`) VALUES 
(5, 15, '1373894222', 'Y', '', '', '17-profile.jpg', '', '', ''), 
(6, 16, '1373925933', 'Y', '', '', '17-profile.jpg', '', '', ''), 
(7, 17, '1373975337', 'Y', 'Midtjylland', 'Hende', '17-profile.jpg', 'Nej', '', 'Y'), 
(13, 23, '1375298672', 'N', 'Midtjylland', 'Hende', '23-profile.jpg', 'Nej', '', 'Y'), 
(14, 24, '1375299707', 'N', '', '', 'no-image.png', '', '', '');
```

Comment: The syntax seems OK, and if there is no error, I assume tables/columns references are valid. Is there *really* any `wp_users` and `sh_users` having the same id? Could you post some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: This is my dupms, and I'm really puzzled

Comment: could you post the table structure as well (`CREATE TABLE...`), this is required in order to test.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux There you go fiddles: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d667b  and  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f57e

Comment: This actually works as expected, I think: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd71/1 :D The problem is *probably not* with the DB. How do you process the result of the query at application level?

Comment: This is very odd... I use it like I normally use wp query: $results = $wpdb->get_results(...QUERY...)  and then when i do print_r($results); it's empty array :( Have no idea what so ever why... All others query do work, only this whith join tables wont :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress. But if you used it before like that that must be something else ?!? Do we need the big artillery here? Anyway, do you have the opportunity to capture the traffic between your PHP server and your DB server in order to check the query and the result returned from the DB? Could you activate the [MySQL query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - thanks for all the help man and sorry for bother - it was file encoding problem - obviously Ultraedit was placing some character and when I convert to UTF-8 all started working normally. How silly was that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the query which table to select the results from -

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT wp_users.user_login, wp_users.user_email, sh_users.user_photo
    FROM wp_users, sh_users
    WHERE wp_users.ID = sh_users.user_id
");
```

This is assuming you want `user_photo` only from your `sh_users` table, so change if that is incorrect.

Also, for troubleshooting purposes, the $wpdb global has several useful class variables. Directly after you run your query, add this code -

```
echo '<pre>Last query: '; print_r($wpdb->last_query); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>Last error: '; print_r($wpdb->last_error); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>Last result: '; print_r($wpdb->last_result); echo '</pre>';
```

If `$wpdb->last_error` returns anything, hopefully it will help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: That doesn't work for me either, always empty results... I really don't know why. All other query work nice, only this with join tables doesn't ? Any idea why always getting empty results ? Once again - NO ERROR thrown, just empty results :(

Comment: Very strange thing... I'm using UltraEdit and it seems that file editing mode wasn't UTF-8 but something else, and probably it placed some stupid character. When I created new UTF-8 file, query started working... Thanks for this !!!!

Comment: Have you run `$wpdb->show_errors();` before you execute the query (`and $wpdb->hide_errors();` after)? If not, errors will not be shown. By default, `$wpdb->query()` will simply return `0` (i.e. no rows affected) if there is an error. It does however record the error data either way, accessed as described above.

Comment: No prob, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isnt correct. You have 2 tables:

1. wp_users
2. sh_users

Too be able to link these 2 you have to join them. Try the following:

```
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
     SELECT user_login, user_email, user_photo
     FROM wp_users
     JOIN sh_user 
     ON wp_users.ID = sh_users.user_id
    ");
```

After this, you do can a `WHERE` or replace the `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` etc..

Comment: While the syntax used by OP is not the most elegant, is is indeed valid. With MySQL, using several table names separated by a comma will perform an implicit join. And you could use `WHERE` clause to select the join condition. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html